# Diagrams in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, diagram

I'm trying to present two types of data as diagrams in my PHP based web application:

- **cake diagram**: showing different types of data for the current user, i.e. incidents and changes received by the user
- **2D bar diagram**: showing basically the same data, but for several users (i.e. incidents for user a, user b and user c; changes for a, b, c; ..)

My first idea was to use a JavaScript library. Although both diagram types are IMHO "standard", only few libraries out there support both types as I noticed after carefully going through Google's results.

I ended up with [jQuery Visualize Plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_visualize_plugin_accessible_charts_graphs_from_tables_html5_canvas/). Unfortunately I can't get it to work in the way I'd like it.

Hence I wanted to ask **what your recommendations are for this requirement**.

Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://raphaeljs.com/

might be helpful.

Comment: wow this looks great.
+1 from me :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/chart/)?

Comment: Tkx kgiannakakis, but I don't like the idea of providing client data to Google..  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also have a look at: [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for the [upcoming ExtJS4](http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/11/22/ext-js-4-preview-faster-easier-more-stable/?utm_source=feedburner), they have moved from Flash to JS-based charting, possibly using the [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) framework mentioned earlier. There is also an overview [here](http://www.ajaxline.com/10-best-free-javascript-charts-solutions).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript - http://www.jscharts.com/

Java Servlet - http://www.jfree.org/eastwood/

Answer (score 0):

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/
I found the solution! It is free BSB License.

Comment: As a side note : as of June 2011, Protovis is no longer active, its authors recommend to use [D3.js](http://d3js.org/)